# Remove duplicates from table based on conditional result and multiple columns

Tags: sql, duplicates, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

```
ID  |  OrgName  |  TaxID  |  IsActive
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Miller   |  111    |     1
1   |  Miller   |  111    |     1      -- Duplicate
1   |  Miller   |  111    |     0      -- Duplicate
1   |  Miller   |  111    |     0      -- Duplicate
2   |  XYZ      |  222    |     0      
2   |  XYZ      |  222    |     0      -- Duplicate
```

I am getting this result by finding the duplicates, but here I wants to remove the based on the result of my column.

My priority is to keep the record which is "**IsActive**" = 1 and remove the other records whether it is 1 or 0.

But if there is not record with "**IsActive**" = 1 then priority goes to keeping any one with 0.
As a result there will be two records - **row 1 and 5**.

Your Help is appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: which sql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cte` to delete duplicates and with `row_number` function

```
insert @table (id,orgname,TaxID,IsActive)
select 1   ,  'Miller'   ,  111   ,     1 union all
select 1   ,  'Miller'   ,  111   ,     1 union all
select 1   ,  'Miller'   ,  111   ,     0 union all
select 1   ,  'Miller'   ,  111   ,     0 union all
select 2   ,  'XYZ'   , 222   ,     0 union all
select 2   ,  'XYZ'   , 222   ,     0
;
with cte as (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by IsActive desc) rn from @table) 
delete from cte  where rn>1
select * from @table
```

Comment: Include `DBMS Product` that has analytical function.

Comment: Hii: this is excluding the records with IsActive with '0' as well, in example  last two rows - from last two row I also wants to keep the any one of them. Thanks! @Ven

Comment: Solution you provided Worked : Thanks!

Comment: @ArpitPatel please accept the answer if it has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, this does what you want:

```
select id, orgname, taxid, max(isactive) as isactive
from t
group by id, orgname, taxid;
```

Comment: Yes: that will give me the result (records that I want to keep) but as I am deleting the rows, I have to skip the first row and be able to delete those other rows.